# Assigning SQL Server DB role to a DB user programatically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to assign a DB role to a DB user in Sql Server 2008 using t-sql? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From BOL:
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db role', @membername = 'db user'

Comment: BOL = Books Online. It's the SQL Server help document. It's the best place to look this kind of thing up (it's actually the best help documentation I've seen on a piece of SW to date).